# _reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.signup is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-router

I am using react native router, but I met this problem which I can solve it. I am using react-native-router-flux version 4.0.6

The Router code:

```
const AppNavigation = () => {
<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
        <Scene key="signin" component={SignInForm} title="SignIn" initial={true}/>
        <Scene key="signup" component={SignUpForm} title="SignUp"/>
    </Stack>
</Router>
}
```

The code for using the router:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.signup()}>
            <Text>Please <Text style={{color:"green"}}>sign up</Text> if you don't have an account</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here's the [error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPTt4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Router component to the first page of App which is mentioned in the Index file? like shown below :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from '../Router';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Router/>
    );
  }
}
```